# how to post aiohttp authenticated request?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to use aiohttp to post an authenticated request, code below, however I got the following error when calling `get_all_balances`:

File "C:\Users\wil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 495, in update_auth
raise TypeError("BasicAuth() tuple is required instead")

I thought I have already inputted the tuple of API key and secret inside `args['auth']` when posting the request, how do I resolve this?

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json


base_url = 'https://api.luno.com'
lapikey = ''
lapisecret = ''


async def do(method, path, req=None, auth=False):
    args = {}
    params = None
    if req:
        try:
            params = json.loads(json.dumps(req))
        except Exception:
            params = None
    if params:
        args = dict(params=params)
    if auth:
        args['auth'] = (lapikey, lapisecret)
    url = make_url(path, params)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession().request(method, url, **args) as res:
        try:
            return await res.json()
        except Exception as e:
            return e

def make_url(path, params):
    if params:
        for k, v in params.items():
            path = path.replace('{' + k + '}', str(v))
    return base_url + '/' + path.lstrip('/')

async def get_all_balances():
    return await do('GET', '/api/1/balance', auth=True)
```

I tried reading the aiohttp.helpers.BasicAuth class code but am at a loss, don't really understand it (am a programming noob).